# Как вывести значение одного из ключей объекта stdClass?

Tags: php

Как вывести значение `im` из этого объекта?

```
object(stdClass)#43 (3) {
  ["num_rows"]=>
  int(1)
  ["row"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["im"]=>
    string(58) "Images/Goods/medium/592778.jpg"
  }
  ["rows"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    array(1) {
      ["im"]=>
      string(58) "Images/Goods/medium/592778.jpg"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `$obj->row['im']` не?

Comment: Доступ к элементам объекта происходит через оператор ->, а все, что находится в этих элементах - обычный массив, доступный через []

Answer (score 1):

```
$var->row['im'];
```

Вместо `var` название переменной которую дампите

Answer (score 0):

```
$testArray = (array) $testObject;
var_dump($testArray);

array(3) {
  ["num_rows"]=>
  int(1)
  ["row"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["im"]=>
    string(30) "Images/Goods/medium/592778.jpg"
  }
  ["rows"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["im"]=>
    string(30) "Images/Goods/medium/592778.jpg"
  }
}
```

Просто сделайте преобразование с помощью (array) и работайте как с массивом

Comment: Думаю не стоит "допиливать" ответы других авторов. Вы можете либо оставить комментарий к ответу, либо дать свой собственный ответ.